# Query optimization that collects and orders nodes on very large graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a decently large graph (1.8 billion nodes and roughly the same number of relationships) where I am performing the follow query:

```
MATCH (n:Article)
WHERE n.id IN $pmids
MATCH (n)-[:HAS_MENTION]->(m:Mention)
WITH n, collect(m) as mentions
RETURN n.id as pmid, mentions
ORDER BY pmid
```

where $pmids are a list of strings, e.g. `["1234", "4567"]` where the length of this list varies from 100-500 length.

I am currently am holding the data within neo4j docker community instance with the following conf modifications: NEO4J_dbms_memory_pagecache_size=32G, NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_max__size=32G. Index has been created for Article.id.

This query has been quite slow to run (roughly 5 seconds) and I would like to optimize to make for faster runtime. As part of work, I have access to neo4j enterprise so one approach would be to ingest this data as part of a neo4j enterprise account where I can tweak advanced configuration settings.

In general, does anyone have any tips in how I may improve performance, whether it be optimizing the cypher query itself, increase workers or other settings in neo4j.conf?

Thanks in advance.

For anyone interested - I posed this question in the [neo4j forums](https://community.neo4j.com/t/query-optimization-that-collects-and-orders-nodes-on-very-large-graph/32896/10) as well and there have already been some interesting optimization suggestions (especially around the "type hint" to trigger backward-indexing, and using pattern comprehension instead of `collect()`

Answer (score 1):

Initial thoughts

- you are using a string field to store PMID, but PMIDs are numeric, it might reduce the database size, and possibly perform better if stored as int (and indexed as int, and searched as int)
- if the PMID list is usually large, and the server has over half dozen cores, it might be worth looking into the apoc parallel cypher functions
- do you really need every property from the Mention nodes? if not try gathering just what you need
- what is the size of the database in GBs? (some context is required in terms of memory settings), and what did neo4j-admin memrec recommend?
- If this is how the db is always used, all the time, a sql database might be better, and when building that sql db, collect the mentions into one field (once and done)

Note: Go PubMed!

Comment: Thanks for your response!
4) the database directory is roughly 330GB - I was actually just reading about apoc.mapParallel and am interested in giving this a go to see what type of speedups I could possibly get
5) Very good point. I originally went for a knowledge graph representation as I thought there may be potentially interesting questions to be asked involving shortest paths and other graph analysis/algorithms. Also this was a general way to "kick the tires" to see how neo4j does for larger graphs :)